# Binder thread interrupt unexpected behavior

Tags: android, multithreading, android-binder

Android `ContentProvider`s use a pool of "binder threads" to process RPCs such as `query`, `insert` and `call`. In my implementation of a `ContentProvider` I am performing a long running task that is interruptible using `Thread#interrupt()`. I wrote a watchdog thread that interrupts the currently executing binder thread under certain circumstances. The interrupt is correctly taking effect but now I noticed that binder thread still has its interrupt flag set when it is used again by android to handle a new RPC. This causes the new RPC to behave as if it was interrupted. I did not expect this. I catch `InterruptedException` but this can happen if the watchdog thread sets the interrupted flag towards the end of the RPC when there is nothing looking at or clearing the flag.

Some ad-hoc testing of `ExecutorService` indicates that when it is reusing threads to handle tasks it resets the interrupt flag sometime before running each task. I found this comment in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class:

```
 * 2. Before running any task, the lock is acquired to prevent
 * other pool interrupts while the task is executing, and
 * clearInterruptsForTaskRun called to ensure that unless pool is
 * stopping, this thread does not have its interrupt set.
```

To correct android's behavior I am thinking that at the beginning of each `ContentProvider` RPC I clear the interrupt flag with `Thread.interrupted()` but that doesn't seem like the most elegant solution.

Can anyone confirm if android binder threads are in fact handling thread interrupts differently from an `ExecutorService`, and what might be the best work-around so the interrupt flag isn't propagated between different RPCs?

Here is some code that can be placed in a `ContentProvider` to reproduce the issue:

```
@Override
public Bundle call(String method, String arg, Bundle extras) {
  Log.w(TAG, "Thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + " before isInterrupted()=" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());

  final Thread callThread = Thread.currentThread();

  if (method.equals("interrupt")) {
    new Thread("interrupter") {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        callThread.interrupt();
      }
    }.start();
  }

  try {
    Thread.sleep(500);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, e);
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }

  Log.w(TAG, "Thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + " after isInterrupted()=" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());

  return null;
}
```

Then in an `Activity` (make sure it is running in a different process from the `ContentProvider`!) hook up two buttons, one that does a regular call and one that does a call which will trigger an interrupt:

```
findViewById(R.id.call).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    getContentResolver().call(CallContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, "", "", null);
  }
});

findViewById(R.id.callint).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    getContentResolver().call(CallContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, "interrupt", "", null);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you let us see your code? It's hard to tell from reading.

Comment: I added some code snippets that can be used to demo the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my best stab so far at a work-around to this problem:

```
private volatile Thread mRunningCallThread;

@Override
public Bundle call(String method, String arg, Bundle extras) {
    Thread.interrupted(); // Clear interrupted flag

    mRunningCallThread = Thread.currentThread(); // Thread to interrupt

    // Do stuff, allowing interruption by another thread

    mRunningCallThread = null;

    Thread.interrupted(); // Clear interrupted flag
}
```

The field `mRunningCallThread` is a pointer to the currently running thread that I may interrupt.